# Flex deploy on tomcat, when open in browser, it is blue blank

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, flash

My project including A.swf and B.swf, A.swf embed in a html file, A.swf will load B.swf after initialed. The project test ok. 
Now I deploy it on tomcat. Open the url http://***:8080/myproject in browser, the screen is blue blank, it seems B.swf is not loaded.
I try some methods: add crossdomain.xml, and trustPlayerFile, also i use apache http server as a proxy. But the problem is not solved.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your tomcat catalog to [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)